# How to get the height according to EGM96 for a point?

Tags: ellipsoid

For a program I have to calculate the height according to EGM96. I found http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm96/egm96.html - this site delivers files with parameters and a fortran-program. But I feel unable to understand what is going on in this Fortran-program and have no idea how to use the parameters to generate the correct height. Can someone explain the algorithm to me?

Comment: Which Fortran program?  The one that interpolates values on a grid (intpt.f) or the one that sums spherical harmonics (f477.f)?

Comment: I don't even get, which one calculate the heights for me.

Comment: They both do, but they do it in (completely) different ways.

Answer (score 3):

[GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net) includes classes to compute the geoid height via interpolation on a grid of values (the [Geoid](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/classGeographicLib_1_1Geoid.html) class) and via summing the spherical harmonic sum (the [GravityModel](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/classGeographicLib_1_1GravityModel.html) class).  The interpolation method is pretty straightforward; see the associated documentation, [Geoid height](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/geoid.html).  I agree that the NGA programs for computing the geoid height via spherical harmonics are poorly documented.  I've tried to explain the method on the documentation page, [Gravity models](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/gravity.html).  More to the point, I'm happy to answer questions.  (I've had no luck getting NGA to answer questions about its programs!)

Answer (score 1):

Pardon if I'm cross-posting a link from Stack Overflow.  I asked a similar question on Stack Overflow with regards how to do the calculations for an IOS application.  I actually ended up answering my own question but I've posted a link here which gives you both C and Objective C code to complete this task.

Code is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196714/wgs84-geoid-height-altitude-offset-for-external-gps-data-on-ios

Somebody ported a Fortran program to do these calculations into C and I then ported it over to Objective C

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C# library for calculating geoid EGM96 undulations:
https://github.com/MatejFranceskin/GeoidHeightsDotNet

Available also as Nuget packet: GeoidHeightsDotNet

Answer (score 0):

There is a JavaScript conversion library here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/egm96-universal